# Offline iphone application Photo and Data Download issue

Tags: ios, iphone, ios5, ios7, ios6

We have developed one iPhone application which is working offline and online mode (Means we store data and photo offline also) and we will display data from iphone only not from webservice.

Hence starting of the application,We call one web service for data which download  the sql queries and one web service for photo which generate the zip file of more than 1000 photos on the server.

But if the number of photos is greater than 2000 at that time we get a server side error for creating zip file. Error description is listed below.

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 52428800 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4186492 bytes)
```

This is memory related issue and we have increased our memory so as now this problem has been resolved, but in future if number of photos will be  greater than 3000 at that time this same error will occur.

So now we are thinking that we should download one by one photo from server. Please give us your valuable feedback and other best option for downloading photos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have do some R&D and find the solution is that divid the download in multiple zip in place of one zip.

It is also reliable for resume the download.

Answer (score 0):

Just check if the image is on the device ..

```
  if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path]){
      // load image
  }
  else{
      // download image
  }
```